# Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.0 - PyDev 5.8.0 Refactoring Error

Tags: eclipse, lucene, refactoring, pydev, eclipse-oxygen

I am using Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.0.I20170612-0950 with PyDev 5.8.0.
When I try to use refactoring I get the following Error message:

`Could not initialize class org.apache.lucene.codesc.Codec$Holder`

The same thing happens when I try to use the Search function (Strg-H)

```
An internal error occurred during: "PyDev Index Search".
Could not initialize class org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec$Holder`
```

Seems to be a problem with Lucene.

I found this post on the Eclipse website https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=510604
But I am not very familiar with Eclipse and it didn't help.

Any Idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug. It's already reported at:

https://www.brainwy.com/tracker/PyDev/830

the plan is fixing it before the next release.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by installing the following feature:

> Name: Dynamic Languages Toolkit - Core Lucene Index Frameworks
>
> Version: 5.8.0.201706030400
>
> Id: org.eclipse.dltk.core.index.lucene.feature.group
>
> Provider: Eclipse DLTK

Answer (score 0):

PyDev Release 5.9.0 (2017-08-10) fixed the problem! 
http://www.pydev.org/

Thank you and keep up the great work!